# How do i store multiple user inputs (String,Int,Double) in an array/arraylist and output the stored data(Java)?

Tags: java

I am working on a lesson of a Car Garage using user input stored in an array and/or arraylist. Those were atleast the specific instructions provided. I am new to programming and lack some technical language. Thanks for your help in advance.

*Current issue: I can accept user input/entry but the last entered car will be the only one saved and outputted.*

```
public class Car {

    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    double price;

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }   
}

public class CarApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    char userCon = 'Y';

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Garage!");

    while(userCon =='Y') {
        System.out.println("How many cars will you be entering?");
            int carAmount = scan.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Car> car = new ArrayList<Car>(carAmount);
            Car carMake = new Car();
            Car carYear = new Car();
            Car carModel = new Car();
            Car carPrice = new Car();

        for(int i =0;i<carAmount;i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the make of the car " + (i + 1) + ":");
            carMake.make = scan.next();

            System.out.println("Enter the model of the car: ");
            carModel.model = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the year: ");
            carYear.year = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the price: ");
            carPrice.price = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Thank you, Car " + (i + 1) + " is set!");

    }       
        System.out.println("The garage is holding " + carAmount + " cars.");
        for(int n =0;n<carAmount;n++) {
            System.out.println("Make: " + carMake.getMake());
            System.out.println("Model: " + carModel.getModel());
            System.out.println("Year: " + carYear.getYear());
            System.out.println("Price: " + carModel.getPrice());

    }   
        System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Y/N");
        String word = scan.next();
        word = word.toUpperCase();
        userCon = word.charAt(0);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You basically read one car and not 4 cars.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: carMake, carYear, carModel and carPrice are not 4 separate objects, but are properties of a single car object. So instead of having separate variables, you assign properties to a single car object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CarApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        char userCon = 'Y';

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Garage!");

        while(userCon =='Y') {
            System.out.println("How many cars will you be entering?");
            int carAmount = scan.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>(carAmount);

            for(int i =0;i<carAmount;i++) {
                Car car = new Car();
                System.out.println("Enter the make of the car " + (i + 1) + ":");
                car.make = scan.next();

                System.out.println("Enter the model of the car: ");
                car.model = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the year: ");
                car.year = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the price: ");
                car.price = scan.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("Thank you, Car " + (i + 1) + " is set!");
                carList.add(car);
            }
            System.out.println("The garage is holding " + carAmount + " cars.");
            for (Car car : carList) {
                System.out.println("Make: " + car.getMake());
                System.out.println("Model: " + car.getModel());
                System.out.println("Year: " + car.getYear());
                System.out.println("Price: " + car.getPrice());
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Y/N");
            String word = scan.next();
            word = word.toUpperCase();
            userCon = word.charAt(0);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
```

You need to create a Car object, and need to assign the values to that particular object for a car. You do this in a loop and add it to carList. After the loop is done, carList contains a list of cars. You need to iterate that list to print your data.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Really appreciate you taking the time. This makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Also, not that you are not using your setters. You are directly assigning `carModel.model` even though you have a `setModel` function.